# How to use categorical data to show a sorted bar graph containing duplicate values

Tags: matlab

I have this sample data:

```
names = ["JFK", "BOS", "YYZ", "LAX"];
values = [1, 2, 2, 3];
```

I create create a [`categorical` array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html):

```
>> cat = categorical(names)

cat = 

  1×4 categorical array

     JFK      BOS      YYZ      LAX
```

And I create a horizontal bar graph with the data:

```
barh(cat, values);
```

and this is how the output looks:

[image: unsorted bar graph]

As you can see the y-axis of the bar graph is sorted automatically in alphabetical order, but I would like to sort the bar graph based on the values instead. Where the category with the largest value is placed at the top of the graph and the one with the smallest value in the bottom of the graph, like this:

```
LAX -| XXXXXXXXX
YYZ -| XXXXXX
BOS -| XXXXXX
JFK -| XXX
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`barh`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/barh.html) indeed says (italics added)

> *By default*, the categories display in alphabetical order.

However, I haven't found an input option to override that "default" behaviour.

A workaround is as follows:

1. Apply `sort` to the values, and get the second output of that function. This tells which order to apply to `cat`.
2. Plot the values without specifying categorical data as first input.
3. Change the axis ticks to the category names. You can use `string` to convert from categories to category names (after applying the appropriate order).

That is:

```
[values_sorted, ind_sort] = sort(values);       % step 1
barh(values_sorted)                             % step 2
set(gca, 'yticklabel', string(cat(ind_sort)))   % step 3
```

---

Another approach, as mentioned in comments, is to create the categorical array with the appropriate order built into it. [Apparently](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html#d117e118265) this can be done as follows (not sure how it works):

```
names = ["JFK", "BOS", "YYZ", "LAX"];
values = [1, 2, 2, 3];
[~, ind_sort] = sort(values);
names_char = cellfun(@char, names, 'UniformOutput', false);
cat = categorical(ind_sort, ind_sort, names_char);
```

So now

```
barh(cat, values)
```

works as intended.

Comment: Thank you Luis, I know your answer is a valid workaround. However, this approach has its risks, like when resizing or zooming into the bar graph, for instance. Apparently it is possible to do the sorting with categorical arrays as described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/404473-put-bars-in-bar-graph-in-ascending-order#answer_323598), but I haven't managed to make it work yet.

Comment: @codeaviator I've edited my answer with an attempted solution, that seems to work, although I don't really know how it does

Comment: Awesome! Your edit is the solution I was looking for. Thank you Luis! :)